# how to send input text value in another view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I am trying to send data from one view to another view using routing .I need to send input field value from one screen to another screen using routing .In other words I have one input field and button .On button click I need to send input field value on another screen using routing

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/pl0C88Ksf5Y8YiSnLxSZ?p=preview

On button click I do like this

```
  moveTonext: function(){
         // new SecondView({ model: new Backbone.Model({ value: this.$("input").val()}) });

         new Router().navigate('secondView/'+this.$("input").val(), { trigger: true });

       },
```

**on routing I do like this**

```
secondView: function(inputtext) {
          alert(inputtext+"---");
          new SecondView();
        }
```

But after that I am getting error this 
**Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined**

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal example that you can post here.

Comment: the error your'e getting is because your'e trying to execute "toJSON" on a non existing model. as it seems, secondView has no model binded to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a model to the constructor of your SecondView object. Otherwise, the call to `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` fails (in `SecondView.render`).

In `router.js`:

```
secondView: function(inputtext) {
    // create or find somemodel and then:
    new SecondView({model: somemodel});
}
```